# install php4 in new server and cPanel

Tags: php, server, cpanel

I'm using new server with php5 , i need to install php4 for one website 
is there anyway to do that  , i can't find php4 in the installation package and hosting company not helping they said need to contact cPanel https://www.cpanel.net/

Comment: Since 2008 PHP 4 is no longer supported (https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/php4-support-on-cpanel-11-50.496811/)

Comment: i know that, there is one big script works with php4 ,upgrade the code will take time . so i need to install php4 for some time only

Comment: Given that the first 5.x version of PHP came out in 2005 (approx 13 years ago), there's ***NO VALID REASON*** why any PHP 4 scripts haven't been updated to at least PHP 5. All of PHP 5 is now EOL, only versions 7.1 and newer are supported. There can't be that many hosts who still support PHP 4 (if any)

Answer (score 2):

Last release of PHP4 (v4.4) went unsupported on August 2008.
From http://php.net/supported-versions.php:

> Each release branch of PHP is fully supported for two years from its
>   initial stable release. During this period, bugs and security issues
>   that have been reported are fixed and are released in regular point
>   releases.
>
> After this two year period of active support, each branch is then
>   supported for an additional year for critical security issues only.
>   Releases during this period are made on an as-needed basis: there may
>   be multiple point releases, or none, depending on the number of
>   reports.
>
> Once the three years of support are completed, the branch reaches its
>   end of life and is no longer supported. A table of end of life
>   branches is available.

From http://php.net/eol.php:

> This page lists the end of life date for each unsupported branch of
>   PHP. If you are using these releases, you are strongly urged to
>   upgrade to a current version, as using older versions may expose you
>   to security vulnerabilities and bugs that have been fixed in more
>   recent versions of PHP.

Here's a table of php releases from v3.0 to v7.0 and their end of life dates (extracted from the link above):

[image]

I can recommend you to migrate / adjust your code into a newer PHP version (it will be easier at the end).